# Why does Chrome ask for my GNOME keyring (Seahorse) password?

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-keyring

I use Google Chrome 12.0 (google-chrome-stable) and [Seahorse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seahorse_%28software%29) on Ubuntu 10.10 (I know Seahorse is not the [GNOME keyring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring), but it might be easier for others to search).

Always when I start Chrome I get a prompt for my keyring password. It seems like Chrome doesn't save anything in it. So, why does Chrome ask for the passoword?

Comment: Did you have CHrome to save your passwords as encrypted? I cannot simulate this on my system

Comment: I don't know. If Chrome asked me some time ago, I could have used this. Where can I check this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, older versions of Chrome must unlock the keyring to be able to check if you've saved passwords for a particular site.  This has been fixed in the [current development version](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel); Chrome will now only prompt to unlock your keyring if it actually needs to retrieve a password from it.  If you don't want to use an unstable version of Chrome, you can work around the issue by passing the `--password-store=basic` option so that Chrome uses it's own password store rather than attempting to use the GNOME keyring.

For more information, see [bug #85285](http://crbug.com/85285) in the Chromium bug tracker.

Comment: I get prompted for my password to unlock the keyring every time Chrome starts, however even if I cancel it, my saved passwords are still available.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, you are life saver :) 

My current command-line, if it helps anyone solving issue!

`nohup /usr/bin/google-chrome-beta --user-data-dir=/home/mayur/.config/google-chrome-beta --flag-switches-begin --enable-tcp-fastopen --enable-spelling-auto-correct --flag-switches-end --password-store=basic &`

Comment: FYI, the problem outlined in the OP is still present in Chromium 37.0.2062.120 (in Debian 7 (Wheezy)).  Thankfully, the workaround presented in this answer still works a treat!